# Why build of package without brew does not work?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to build wireshark same way brew is doing it:

```
13:48 marko@marko-mpbr:/tmp $ brew fetch wireshark
==> Downloading http://www.wireshark.org/download/src/wireshark-1.8.6.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/wireshark-1.8.6.tar.bz2
SHA1: 0f51ed901b5e07cceb1373f3368f739be8f1e827
SHA256: 2722ed3e926c26648faec31a81b7881d829df85762c21794b9dd9e4f227331ea
13:49 marko@marko-mpbr:/tmp $ tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/wireshark-1.8.6.tar.bz2
13:49 marko@marko-mpbr:/tmp $ cd wireshark-1.8.6/
13:49 marko@marko-mpbr:/tmp/wireshark-1.8.6 $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/wireshark/1.8.6-marko
[skip]
checking for GTK+ - version >= 2.12.0 and < 3.0... no
*** Could not run GTK+ test program, checking why...
*** The test program failed to compile or link. See the file config.log for the
*** exact error that occured. This usually means GTK+ is incorrectly installed.
configure: error: Neither Qt nor GTK+ 2.12 or later are available, so Wireshark can't be compiled
```

What does brew do differently? Why does build succeeds in brew, but not when I am doing it? All configure parameters are the same. Maybe something in environment?

Comment: What does `config.log` say?

Comment: I have already found what's going on. Look my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must include `/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig` into PKG_CONFIG_PATH:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/X11/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

before executing `configure`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by running with `--with-x`, that is `brew install wireshark --with-x`. According to the formula (`/usr/local/Library/Formula/wireshark.rb`), the available options are `--with-x` and `--with-qt`.